# Garbage characters getting printed by just taking input and printing output

Tags: swift, xcode

I have written a small program to take input from standard input and printing it to standard output. Strangely, some garbage characters are getting printed too.

I tried the same program on an online platform (repl.it) and it is working perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

let input = FileHandle.standardInput

while (true) {
    let inputData = input.availableData

    if var text = String(data: inputData, encoding: .utf8) {
        text = String(text[..<text.index(before: text.endIndex)])
        print(text)
    }
}


INPUT -> 4.44|AB "h"
OUTPUT -> 4.44|AB "h
INPUT -> 4.44|AB "h ab"
OUTPUT -> 4.44|AB "h" ab
```

Can anyone point out what's the issue?

**EDIT:** I am facing this issue in Xcode only. If I use swiftc from command line, it works as expected.

Comment: I cannot yet reproduce the problem. What does `print(text.debugDescription)` print?

Comment: IN -> 4.44|PQ "dsf f"
OUT -> "4.44|PQ \"dsf f\""
IN -> 4.44|PQ "dsf fdsf"
OUT -> "4.44|PQ \"dsf f\"dsf"
IN -> 4.44|PQ "dsfdsf f"
OUT -> "4.44|PQ \"dsf f\"dsf", Still getting those garbage chars